# How can I use "paginate ()" and checklist at the same time with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a table in which data must be entered, but when using paginate() when I try to store the data, only the current page is stored and not the one previously edited. It only happens with checkboxes.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $pensums = sizeof($request->input('course_id'));
    $id = $request->input('grade_id');
    $course_id = $request->input('course_id');

    $data = Pensum::where('grade_id', $id)
        ->update([
            'status' => 'INACTIVE',
        ]);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $pensums; $i++) {
        $data = Pensum::where('grade_id', $id)
            ->where('course_id', $course_id[$i])
            ->update([
                'status' => 'ACTIVE',
            ]);
    }

    $grade_id = $request->input('grade_id');

    return redirect()->action('PensumController@detail', ['grade_id' => $grade_id])
        ->with(['status' => 'Successful upgrade']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use paginate Laravel refresh the page, so, Your checked checkboxes no more remain checked.

Your input tag for checkbox should be as below

```
<input value="" type="checkbox" name="" class="mobile_hide" 
 onchange="loadingIdChange(this,'You have the pass id here')" '+(isChecked ? 'checked' : '')+'/>
```

You need to check the array selectedCheckboxes.

```
var isChecked = isIdAlreadyAdded(data[0],selectedCheckboxes);
```

You should use jQuery to store your checked checkboxes to an array.

```
var selectedCheckboxes = []; //Array where you store checked checkbox IDs.
```

This function will call whenever checkbox checked or unchecked.

```
function checkboxChange(checkbox, id){
     if(checkbox.checked == true){
            if(!isIdAlreadyAdded(id,selectedCheckboxes)){
                selectedCheckboxes.push(id);
            }
        }else{
            removeIfExits(id,selectedCheckboxes);
       }
}
```

This function will check is ID in array selectedCheckboxes.

```
function isIdAlreadyAdded(id,arr){
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] == id){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This function for removing ID if checkbox status is unchecked.

```
function removeIfExits(id,arr){
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] == id){
                delete arr[i];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful.